# Retiring as room owner

Tags: discussion, chat

I am writing this post to announce that I am **retiring as a room owner of our SFF chat room**.

The reason is simple: I haven't been active in chat for the last 10 months or so.  As some of you know, real life has been keeping me occupied for some time now.  I believe that good room moderation requires a level of chat activity that I cannot currently provide or guarantee.

I want to emphasize that my retirement has nothing do with the recent change in the chat room, nor does it have to do with Slytherincess' recent stepping down as a room owner.  I came to this decision prior to both events.  However, I postponed this announcement to ensure it would not be misinterpreted as being connected to the demise / rebirth of the room, and also in case there was a need for increased room owner presence during the early days of the new chat room.

We have a solid team of moderators and room owners, and I am certain my departure will not harm anything.  I want to thank our moderators for their support, dedication, and wisdom, which made being a room owner easier at some hectic times!

I've made many new friends amongst you through chat over the last three years and I'm honoured to have been one of your elected room owners!  In particular, one of my fondest experiences on the site has been organizing **chat room movie nights** from Autumn 2015 to Autumn 2016 — thanks to all those who joined in!

Lastly, I am retiring as a room owner, but not from chat and not from the main site.  I hope to see many of you around in the Restaurant in the near future!

[image]

Comment: [Good luck to you, sir](http://digitalspyuk.cdnds.net/15/38/640x320/landscape_yoda-dumbledore-gandalf.jpg) ;)

Comment: [Thanks for all your work and all the best!](http://laviemegan.umwblogs.org/files/2012/02/trollquote2.jpg)

Comment: [Hope your activity will pick up soon!](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-0NDFcEY1MqY/WXZBv9sQJKI/AAAAAAAABHc/bR40T8Xihiooh6h2tzIiHRKj1hZ5_VlygCK8BGAs/s500/2017-07-24.png)

Comment: [Thanks Praxis](http://www.kappit.com/img/pics/21060480ifbga_sm.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for all the support you gave me while we were room owners together -- it was much appreciated :)

Comment: @Slytherincess: Likewise!  Thank you for the constant support, camaraderie, and wisdom.  It was wonderful serving alongside you!  I hope to catch up with you in chat in the near future. :-)

Comment: So long, and thanks for all the fish!

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Emrakul was a good mod over Puzzling.SE, right?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος No idea

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Oh I thought you were referring to Puzzling.SE's mod retirement "So long, and thanks for all the herrings."

Comment: Oh. No. Our new room name is from H2G2.

Comment: Downvoted, because the quote phrase comes from Star Wars, not Dr. Who. And the image comes from Star Trek. Good luck, nevertheless!